# Hardware recommendations - are feasible here?

Tags: discussion

As hardware and software has to live together, are questions about hardware recommendations feasible on SR? I couldn't find "Hardware Recommendations" SE site.

Comment: There isn't a hardware recommendations SE site, and I don't really think those questions belong here. The hardware for a task would change annually or more often. Software tends to last longer.

Answer (score 4):

Simply put: Nope.

Longer: Nope; it was loosely discussed a few times on area 51, chat and meta and everyone agreed that they were not on topic. You are correct there is no HR **yet**; however join [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) (SE's alpha/beta page) and follow/contribute to the [the Hardware Recommendations proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations).